# visual c++ Sort List of Custom Class

Tags: sorting, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a class student, defined in `class_student.h` like this:

```
#pragma once
using namespace System;
using System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace MySql::Data::MySqlClient;

public ref class student {

public:
    String^ user_name;
    String^ my_class;
    int weighted_grades;
    int weighted_totals;
    float average_percent;

    int get_weighted_grades() {
        String^ con_string = L"datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=1234;database=comp4;";
        MySqlConnection^ con_database = gcnew MySqlConnection(con_string);
        MySqlCommand^ get_grades = gcnew MySqlCommand("select coalesce(sum(method_marks) + sum(accuracy_marks), 0) from tbl_grades inner join tbl_test_instances on tbl_grades.test_instance=tbl_test_instances.id inner join tbl_students on tbl_test_instances.student_id = tbl_students.username inner join tbl_tests on tbl_test_instances.test_id=tbl_tests.test_id where tbl_students.class = tbl_tests.class and username='" + user_name + "';", con_database);
        MySqlDataReader^ my_reader;
        int grades;
        try {
            con_database->Open();
            my_reader = get_grades->ExecuteReader();
            my_reader->Read();
            grades = my_reader->GetInt32(0);
        }
        catch (Exception^ ex) {
            MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
        }
        return grades;
    }

    int get_weighted_totals() {
        String^ con_string = L"datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=1234;database=comp4;";
        MySqlConnection^ con_database = gcnew MySqlConnection(con_string);
        MySqlCommand^ get_totals = gcnew MySqlCommand("select coalesce(sum(method_marks) + sum(accuracy_marks), 0) from tbl_questions inner join tbl_test_questions on tbl_questions.question_id=tbl_test_questions.question_id inner join tbl_test_instances on tbl_test_questions.test_id=tbl_test_instances.test_id inner join tbl_students on tbl_test_instances.student_id=tbl_students.username inner join tbl_tests on tbl_test_instances.test_id=tbl_test_questions.test_id where tbl_students.class=tbl_tests.class and username='" + user_name + "';", con_database);
        MySqlDataReader^ my_reader;
        int totals;
        try {
            con_database->Open();
            my_reader = get_totals->ExecuteReader();
            my_reader->Read();
            totals = my_reader->GetInt32(0);
        }
        catch (Exception^ ex) {
            MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
        }
        return totals;
    }

    student(String^ user_name, String^ txt_class) {
        this->user_name = user_name;
        this->my_class = txt_class;
        this->weighted_grades = get_weighted_grades();
        this->weighted_totals = get_weighted_totals();
        this->average_percent = ((float)weighted_grades / (float)weighted_totals) * 100;
    }

};
```

I have a List `List<student^>^ students = gcnew List<student^>();` defined in another header file (with the class file included). This list has several instances of the class student added to it.

I would like to use `students->Sort()` or something of the like to sort through this list. I tried overwriting the `operator<`, both inside the class definition and outside it, but when I call `Sort()` I still get an error message saying that the items cannot be compared.

When trying to do this through the `operator<`, I used this, if that helps:

```
#pragma once
using namespace System;
using System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace MySql::Data::MySqlClient;

public ref class student {

public:
    String^ user_name;
    String^ my_class;
    int weighted_grades;
    int weighted_totals;
    float average_percent;

    int get_weighted_grades() {
        String^ con_string = L"datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=1234;database=comp4;";
        MySqlConnection^ con_database = gcnew MySqlConnection(con_string);
        MySqlCommand^ get_grades = gcnew MySqlCommand("select coalesce(sum(method_marks) + sum(accuracy_marks), 0) from tbl_grades inner join tbl_test_instances on tbl_grades.test_instance=tbl_test_instances.id inner join tbl_students on tbl_test_instances.student_id = tbl_students.username inner join tbl_tests on tbl_test_instances.test_id=tbl_tests.test_id where tbl_students.class = tbl_tests.class and username='" + user_name + "';", con_database);
        MySqlDataReader^ my_reader;
        int grades;
        try {
            con_database->Open();
            my_reader = get_grades->ExecuteReader();
            my_reader->Read();
            grades = my_reader->GetInt32(0);
        }
        catch (Exception^ ex) {
            MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
        }
        return grades;
    }

    int get_weighted_totals() {
        String^ con_string = L"datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=1234;database=comp4;";
        MySqlConnection^ con_database = gcnew MySqlConnection(con_string);
        MySqlCommand^ get_totals = gcnew MySqlCommand("select coalesce(sum(method_marks) + sum(accuracy_marks), 0) from tbl_questions inner join tbl_test_questions on tbl_questions.question_id=tbl_test_questions.question_id inner join tbl_test_instances on tbl_test_questions.test_id=tbl_test_instances.test_id inner join tbl_students on tbl_test_instances.student_id=tbl_students.username inner join tbl_tests on tbl_test_instances.test_id=tbl_test_questions.test_id where tbl_students.class=tbl_tests.class and username='" + user_name + "';", con_database);
        MySqlDataReader^ my_reader;
        int totals;
        try {
            con_database->Open();
            my_reader = get_totals->ExecuteReader();
            my_reader->Read();
            totals = my_reader->GetInt32(0);
        }
        catch (Exception^ ex) {
            MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
        }
        return totals;
    }

    student(String^ user_name, String^ txt_class) {
        this->user_name = user_name;
        this->my_class = txt_class;
        this->weighted_grades = get_weighted_grades();
        this->weighted_totals = get_weighted_totals();
        this->average_percent = ((float)weighted_grades / (float)weighted_totals) * 100;
    }
    bool operator<(student^ other) {
        return this->average_percent > other->average_percent;
    }
};
```

Or this:

class_student.h:

```
[class definition as shown at the top]

bool operator<(student^ s1, student^ s2);
```

class_student.cpp:

```
#include "class_student.h"

bool operator<(student^ s1, student^ s2) {
    return s1->average_percent > s2->average_percent;
}
```

Comment: This is not C++, but some dialect (C++/CLI maybe?). Please retag accordingly (use the [edit] link for that).

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks. I'm pretty new to c++ and visual studio so I wasn't aware. I changed the tag. I've seen CLI before when making this so I believe that's it.

Comment: How to pass a comparer to the Sort() method is described very well in the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s(v=vs.100).aspx).  Do consider to let the dbase engine do the sort, include an ORDER BY clause in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commenter noted, this is C++/CLI, not C++. If you want to write C++, I recommend that you create an actual C++ project. If you want to write managed code, I recommend that you create a C# project. C++/CLI is intended to serve as a bridge between managed languages (such as C#) and C++, and it generally should not be used for primary application development.

You need to implement interface [`IComparable<student^>^`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx?cs-lang=cpp), rather than implementing an operator.

In .Net, operators cannot be specified in an interface, therefore the `IComparable<T>` interface specifies the method `CompareTo(T)`, which returns `-1` if `this < other`, `0` if equal, and `1` if greater.

For consistency and best practices, you should also override `equals` and `hashCode`, and implement `IEquatable<T>` as well.